# Falha com a função st_intersection()

Tags: r

```
library(sf)
library(geobr)
library(tidyverse)
```

Estou tendo dificuldades em usar o `st_intersection()` do pacote `sf` para determinados dados carregados com o pacote `geobr`.

Por exemplo, se tento fazer uma interseção entre o sf de um estado e um sf das **Unidades de Conservação** do país, não consigo:

```
ucs <- read_conservation_units()

paraiba <- read_state(code_state = "PB")
```

Se tento fazer a interseção, surge a seguinte mensagem:

```
st_intersection(ucs, paraiba)

Error in s2_geography_from_wkb(x, oriented = oriented, check = check) : 
  Evaluation error: Found 5 features with invalid spherical geometry.
[402] Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 3 is degenerate (duplicate vertex)
[820] Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 3 is degenerate (duplicate vertex)
[1394] Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 3 is degenerate (duplicate vertex)
[1429] Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 3 is degenerate (duplicate vertex)
[1555] Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 3 is degenerate (duplicate vertex).
```

Por outro lado, se utilizo a mesma lógica para fazer a interseção entre os **biomas**, a função `st_intersection()` funciona:

```
biomas <- read_biomes()

biomas_paraiba <- st_intersection(biomas, paraiba)
```

Verificando o `biomas_paraiba`:

```
biomas_paraiba

Simple feature collection with 3 features and 8 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -38.7656 ymin: -8.302955 xmax: -34.79288 ymax: -6.026569
Geodetic CRS:  SIRGAS 2000
        name_biome code_biome year code_state abbrev_state name_state code_region name_region                           geom
2         Caatinga          2 2019         25           PB    Paraíba           2    Nordeste MULTIPOLYGON (((-35.22321 -...
4   Mata Atlântica          4 2019         25           PB    Paraíba           2    Nordeste MULTIPOLYGON (((-35.23148 -...
7 Sistema Costeiro         NA 2019         25           PB    Paraíba           2    Nordeste MULTIPOLYGON (((-35.00158 -...
```

E o plot:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = biomas_paraiba, aes(fill = name_biome))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em suma: porque consigo fazer a interseção com os biomas, mas não consigo com as unidades de conservação?

Comment: Veja a mensagem de erro, um dos shapefiles (provavelmente o de UCs) possui geometria inválidas, o que é bastante comum. Experimente usar `sf::st_make_valid` antes da intersecção.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente com o `sf::st_make_valid` . Obrigado @CarlosEduardoLagosta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compartilhando mais informações: a mensagem de erro mencionada ocorre quando se trabalha a partir da versão 1.0 do pacote `sf`, conforme o Pebesma explica [nesse post](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1649).

Ao que parece, a partir da versão 1.0 houve uma mudança na forma como o `sf` trabalha com a geometria S2.

Assim, creio que há duas possibilidades além daquela apresentada pelo @CarlosEduardoLagosta caso se esteja trabalhando com a versão 1.0:

1. utiliza-se a função "sf_use_sf2(FALSE)" antes de realizar certas operações (como `st_intersection()`, por exemplo);
2. instalar a versão anterior à versão 1.0 do pacote `sf`